# Cannot add new Certificates to Android Device

Tags: certificates, https

Using a Pixel 6a, running Android 13.

I am trying to install certificates from a private CA I have established on the internal network. I was able to install the root certificate by doing the following:

Settings > Security & Privacy > More security settings > Encryption & credentials > Install a certificate

From there I am able to select the `ca.crt` file I had copied from the CA server. I can see this new certificate when I hit "Trusted credentials" under the "User" section.

When I try to repeat those exact same steps to add a server specific cert, it's never added as I can't see it under "Trusted credentials". There is no error NOR a confirmation that this certificate was applied successfully.

Edit: When I successfully install the CA cert, I get a small tooltip/popup saying it's been installed successfully. When trying to install the non-root certs, I get no confirmation, and am simply returned to the previous UI view.

Comment: If you have installed the root CA certificate you don't need to install the server certificate, too. It is already trusted by the installed root CA cert. Note that user installed CA certificates will by default not affect most apps. Only a few like Chrome will accept it as a user certificate.